# Java: Is a|=b equivalent to a = a || b for boolean values?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I'm having some problems understanding this code: `a|=b`

Is it equivalent to `a = a || b` ?

Sorry I forgot to mention that a and b are `boolean` values.

It's the same for boolean values.

Comment: It is the same as `a = a | b`

Comment: @Markus Maybe you would like to change your question to ask for equivalency (as your title does) instead of similarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well to make the answer more complete, and despite what the others answered, in your case where

> a and b are boolean values

the two are equivalent (not the same big difference) meaning they have the same result as:

```
a || b
```

and

```
a | b
```

are `true` if either one of them is `true`.

But if your variables are not `boolean` then the equivalency is not true either.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to know, so I'm right. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No. It means `a = a | b`, where `|` is `bitwise OR`

```
a || b
```

is `logical OR` where `a` and `b` should evaluate to `boolean`

**Edit:** If `a` and `b` are `booleans`, then `a | b` and `a || b` leads to same result

Comment: and when `a` and `b` are booleans (which is the only situation the question makes sense IMO)?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  Why do four thoughtless upvoters think that there's some difference between "logical" and "bitwise" when it comes to boolean values?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they're equivalent when both operands are of type `boolean` or `Boolean`.

This is a special case where the `bitwise or`, `|`, operator becomes equivalent to the `logical or` operator, `||`.

Here's a relevant part of the docs: [JLS 15.22.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2)

To understand why, just think of booleans as one bit, `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 3):

Shortcuts like "X is equivalent to Y" are easy to remember, but might lead to errors in certain edge cases. Thus I'm going to be a little pedantic here. Also I'll only cover the `|` operator, because its difference with `||` has been discussed already.

According to [§15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1
>   is evaluated only once.

Note that there are two differences: a cast and the number of evaluations.

The question claims that `a` is a `boolean` **value**, but a value cannot be assigned to. I suppose that the intended meaning was that it is a variable declared as `boolean`. It could also be a variable declared with a different type and just storing a `boolean` value. This would impact the cast, as it is based on declared types, not on types of values stored in them during execution.

In a more general case, if `a` was an expression with a side-effect, the number of evaluations would matter. E.g., consider `arr[i++] |= b` vs. `arr[i++] = arr[i++] | b`.

Answer (score 0):

They are only equivalent if `a` and `b` are both side-effect free (for example, they are both boolean variables).

If either `a` or `b` has side-effects, then they are not equivalent.

First, if `b` has side-effects, and `a` is a simple variable, then `a |= b` is equivalent to `a = a | b`. The difference between `a | b` and `a || b` is that `a | b` will always evaluate both operands, whereas `a || b` will cut short if `a` turns out to be true.

For example, given the following method:

```
static boolean f() {
    System.out.println("Boo!");
    return true;
}
```

the code

```
boolean a = false;
a = a || f();
a = a || f();
```

will output `Boo!` once, whereas

```
boolean a = false;
a |= f();
a |= f();
```

will output `Boo!` twice.

Secondly, if `a` has side-effects, `a |= b` is not even equivalent to `a = a | b` anymore, because `a |= b` will only evaluate `a` once.

Thus (given the array is large enough), after:

```
int i = 0;
arr[i++] = arr[i++] || f();
```

the value of `i` will be 2, whereas after

```
int i = 0;
arr[i++] |= f();
```

the value of `i` will be 1.